# SQL: Add new Primary Key Column to Database Table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a database table with several columns where some of them used to form the primary key together. Now the model changed and a single primary key column, called 'id', gets introduced.

When I alter the table and add the column, the column gets populated in every row with an default value, 0 or NULL, so that it can not be used as a candidate for a new primary key. To achieve that, I have to have a different (numerical) value for 'id' in every row. How can I achieve that, preferably as generic as possible (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server).

Comment: The _philosophy_ around adding a surrogate key column to a table translates across platforms, but the _code_ to execute that is going to be fairly platform specific. For instance, Oracle and Microsoft both have `SEQUENCE` objects and `IDENTITY` columns available, though with different syntax. MySQL uses `AUTO_INCREMENT` rather than `IDENTITY` and doesn't have `SEQUENCE` objects at all. Are you looking for the generic theoretical answer, or a specific solution for the platform you're on?

Comment: I would suggest you use a better name than "id". It is a pet peeve of mine when columns change their names based on the table they are in. If you have say a Claims table the ClaimID is a ClaimID no matter what table it is in. But the task at hand is complicated because you have to handle all the relational values. This is no small task. You have to update tables in the correct order and remove existing primary and foreign keys on the tables affected. Then assign new foreign key values. It isn't as easy as it sounds. But not impossible.

Comment: the name 'id' is actually not the one I am using internally. And, yes, I am looking for a generic theoretical answer.

Comment: This is too broad for a generic answer aside from the 2-3 sentences in my comment above. This is going to be dependent on local dialect (meaning it changes a bit for each DBMS you are working with) and logically challenging to keep relational data related.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of how to add an identity column that populates as a primary key.

```
create table #t (vals varchar(100))

insert into #t
values('a'),('b'),('c')

alter table #t
add ID int identity primary key

select * from #t
```

Results:

```
vals    ID
a   1
b   2
c   3
```

This is a SQL Server answer. I don't know how the other databases work.

Comment: If you already have a composite primary key defined, then you will have to drop that index before creating a new primary key.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int
);
```

Might be this will be helpful.
The MS SQL Server uses the `IDENTITY` keyword to perform an auto-increment feature.

In the example above, the starting value for `IDENTITY` is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each new record.

**Tip:** To specify that the "ID" column should start at value 10 and increment by 5, change it to `IDENTITY(10,5)`.

To insert a new record into the "Persons" table, we will NOT have to specify a value for the "ID" column (a unique value will be added automatically):